# Wiring 3 way light fixture with pass through

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'm an idiot and forgot how the original light fixture was wired.

These are the wires in the box. This light fixture is controlled by two different switches. I also believe that power is being passed down further to another outdoor light and a socket in the next room.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/kdBZnNr.png]

When I connected the two black wires to each other, the two white wires to the light fixture white wire, and the red wire to the light fixture black wire, the pass through works (the outdoor light and other socket work), but the light fixture itself doesn't light up.

I tried a couple of other combinations of wires (capped red, all 3 blacks together, 2 whites together), but this way the light fixture doesn't turn off.

The weird thing is I used a multimeter on the red to ground and to white and it was reading 120V...

Any ideas what to do here?

Picture here: https://imgur.com/a/3ZbJV5k

In the picture the two black wires are joined via a nut

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch boxes please?

Comment: Drawings are nice, but they generally miss a bit of reality that's important. Pics of the wiring (do NOT remove any wires from anything) at both switches that control this would be helpful too.

Comment: Just added a photo of the inside of the wiring

Comment: I see the photo, but you're still showing us only the fixture. The problem is probably in one of the switch boxes. We need to see those.